# Rails and Websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

So I want to be able to get a live stream of notifications for my users that are using my rails application. I heard that you are able to do this using web sockets but I haven't seen anything about it in rails.

Is there a way to do this in rails or am I able to use something else along side my application such as node.js ?

Comment: I found example for you https://github.com/moaa/websocket-rails-demo

Comment: There're either Rails SSE (`ActionController::Live`) or Websockets (mostly applied with `faye-rails` gem). Both of them have some pros and cons, e.g: SSE - need a multithreaded environment (possible issues with non-thread safe gems) or [Live streaming threads not dying](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10989), Websockets run only within Thin container.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I started searching for different terms and I was able to find Faye

This tutorial is great for it http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails--net-22600

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like PubNub http://www.pubnub.com/

They support a good amount of languages/libraries such as AngularJS. Great customer service and documentation. Also many examples such as this one: http://www.pubnub.com/developers/data-streams/twitter-stream